# How to display a feature only if custom field value is set?

Tags: conditional-tags

What i'm trying to do here is to modify the existing wp-postratings plugin. The function to display the ratings is:

```
<?php if(function_exists('the_ratings')) { the_ratings(); } ?>
```

However, the above code displays the ratings on every post. What would be the conditional statement to add such that if a post has a custom field with name/value as ratings/yes

This way, based on the conditional statement, the ratings would be displayed only on posts where the custom field has the ratings/yes added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
// get the value of our custom field
$meta_value = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'ratings', true);
// if it's not empty and the_ratings function exists:
if( !empty($meta_value) && function_exists('the_ratings') ){
    the_ratings();
}
```

Comment: Thanks.. but this code doesn't seem to do anything. The ratings have disappeared from all the posts now. I've set the custom field/value to ratings/yes.

Comment: sorry, updated it to change `$post_id` to `$post->ID`, which will actually exist if you're using this in the loop.